# Clutch burning smell after wooden ramp of crappy garage

Tags: clutch, audi

Recently my tyre went flat and so I drove .5 miles to the nearest tyre garage which was asking my to drive up their wodden planks into the bodyshop. It was refusing to go up (unsure if it was stuck on a ramp) - and I was pushing it hard with then directions of the garage guys to keep going - I saw some smoke from the front left tyre and smelt clutch and decided to stop and make them change the tyre at front of the garage. The clutch still smelt strong as I drove away and now a week later whenever I drive the car for long, I can smell the clutch smell linger around. The clutch still works as I tested it by taking off in 3rd gear etc. Just wondering if I've botched it and should get a replacement asap or not? I drive an AUDI A5 TFSI 2.0 if necessary! Thanks :/

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It may be a pointless question, but are you sure that it's a toasty clutch smell and not another burning smell? Were you riding the clutch on the ramp?

Answer (score 1):

You may not have been smelling clutch burn. If the tire was spinning on the rim, you'd get burning and smell, and it fits your description of smoke from that area.

If you did not slip the clutch to get up the ramp, there's likely no damage there. You could, at an extreme level, remove the left front wheel and move it away from the vehicle. The smell may follow the wheel, and the vehicle will lose the odor.